# How to construct space that having arbitrary homotopy group?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I'm studying Algebraic topology.

I want to construct $X$ that for given $\{G_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$,  $\pi_n (X)$ is isomorphic to $G_n$ for all $n$.

First, I will use CW complex $K(G_n , n)$. If we make $X_k = \Pi_{i=1}^k K(G_i, i)$ then we get $\pi_n (X)$ is isomorphic to $G_n$ for all $n \leq k$. But I have trouble on extending it to the infinity.

In Hatcher's exercise, if we make inclusion $X_k \subseteq X_{k+1}$ by regarding $X_k$ as the subcomplex of $X_{k+1}$ with $n$th coordinate equal to a basepoint 0-cell of $K(G_{k+1}, k+1)$, then we can make $X = \cup_i X_i $ that satisfies $\pi_n (X)$ is isomorphic to $G_n$ for all $n$. I want to show this. Can you help me?

Comment: can't you use compactness of $S^n$ to make an argument about it landing in finitely many product factors?

Comment: You need to assume that each $G_n$ is abelian for $n\ge 2$.

Comment: @AndresMejia No (because of Tychonoff's Theorem). However you can use the universal property of the product to check that $\prod^\infty_{i=1}K(G_i,i)$ has the correct homotopy groups.

Comment: @Tyrone, I think if we want $X$ as a CW-complex **also**, then just the product(with usual product topology) does not work. But, yeah, OP has asked for a topological space.

Comment: @Sumanta correct, the product will not even be homotopy equivalent to a CW complex. However as you point out, it will be a *space* with the correct homotopy groups. Recalling that every space can be approximated up to weak equivalence by a CW complex, one could take a CW replacement of the product to obtain a CW complex with the correct homotopy groups. Unfortunately I do not know of any nice description of the result.

Comment: ah @Tyrone thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: What's wrong with taking the infinite product $\Pi_k^{\infty} K(G_k,k)$?